# I'm trying to read a table spanning across multiple pages with static web url in R, but the code grabs first page rows again and again

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, static

I'm trying to extract a table that contains price information spanning multiple pages, but with a static URL. The code reads only page - 1 and keeps duplicating those rows 4 times. Can someone help me fixing the code to extract the data across multiple pages?

```
library(plyr)
require(stringi)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)

fetchAll <- function(page) {
  url <- paste0("http://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=78&Tx_State=TN&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2012&DateTo=01-Dec-2014&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2012&To_Date=01-Dec-2014&Tx_Trend=0&Tx_CommodityHead=Tomato&Tx_StateHead=Tamil+Nadu&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--", page, "-hs-code.html")
  url2 <- read_html(url)
  url3 <- url2%>%html_nodes("table")%>%.[1]%>%html_table(fill = TRUE)
  url4 <- data.frame(url3)
}

allData <- ldply(1:4, fetchAll, .progress="text")

View(allData)
```

Comment: Analyze the web site better. Maybe they set cookies on the first access, and redirect to the first page of results when the cookie is missing. When you paste a URL into a new, private window of your browser, and see the next page, then the URL works.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried opening the link in a private window, but the url doesn't change on clicking next. Its the same. I'm not able to read the table that is spanning across these multiple pages. Can you please tell me how this can be done? - @RolandWeber